# Why some people feel their skin itching when they're told about insects and no insects happen to be nearby?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

Sometimes when people talk in public about cockroaches, for example, it happens for some people to feel the skin itching and yet, no cockroaches were there. Is there a name for this phenomenon?

Answer (score 4):

The name you are looking for is [Formication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formication).

> Formication is the medical term for a sensation that exactly resembles that of small insects crawling on (or under) the skin. It is one specific form of a set of sensations known as [paresthesias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paresthesia), which also include the more common prickling, tingling sensation known as "pins and needles". Formication is a well documented symptom, which has numerous possible causes.